# Recovering HDD Space From Failed Linux Install

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, multi-boot, disk-space

I had a dual-boot (Windows/Linux) on my laptop a while back, but the Linux partition became corrupted when I tried to install a different version of Linux and overwrite the previous one.

How do I identify the space on my HDD that is taken up by the corrupted Linux partition and make it usable once again so that I can retry my Linux install?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming by "corrupted" you just mean that Linux won't boot or is broken for some reason.

If this is the case, you don't have to do anything to "make it usable again." Distributions like Ubuntu typically have a good installer that shows your drives partitions and lets you choose where to install. If you just want to start over with your Linux partition, make sure you know which one it is, and choose that partition in the installer. The installer will take care of the rest to make the drive ready for installation.

From Windows, you can right click on My Computer, select Manage, and then use the Disk Utility to see the partitions. This will let you see their sizes and labels to help know which one to use for Linux.